# $p$ ramifies in a number field, then it does so in an overfield

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If $p$ ramifies in a number field $K$, and we have number field extensions $F:K:\mathbb{Q}$, does it follow that $p$ ramifies in $F$? Please give me some hints. If true, I'll need to work out a direct proof of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ramification index is multiplicative in towers of extensions. If $F/K/Q$ is a tower of extensions, $P_1$ a prime ideal in $Q$, $P_2$ a prime ideal in $K$ with $P_2\cap Q=P_1$, and $P_3$ a prime ideal in $F$ with $P_3\cap K=P_2$, then $e(P_3\mid P_1)=e(P_3\mid P_2)\cdot e(P_2\mid P_1)$.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L/K/\mathbb{Q}$ be an extension of number fields. First notice that if $I$ is an ideal in $O_K$, we can define an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_L$, $I\mathcal{O}_L$ to be the ideal generated by all the elements of $I$. (This notation can, in fact, be used to denote the ideal in $\mathcal{O}_L$ generated by the elements of any set $I$.)

We know we have unique factorisation of ideals into primes, for ideals in $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$. Suppose that in $K, (p) =p\mathcal{O}_K = P_1^{e_1}\dots P_n^{e_n}$. Then in $L$, $(p)=p\mathcal{O}_L=(P_1\mathcal{O}_L)^{e_1}\dots (P_n\mathcal{O}_L)^{e_n}$. Whilst the $P_i\mathcal{O}_L$ aren't necessarily primes, the prime factors of $P_i\mathcal{O}_L$ have ramification index at least $e_i$. Thus if $p$ ramifies in $K$, it ramifies in $L$.

Comment: I already know this, but thank you. Your notation is inconsistent ($F$'s and $L$'s are meant to refer to the same thing.) I prefer Dietrich's answer because it says more than 'the ramification index is at least $e_i$'.

Comment: @user71815 Thanks for the correction, I usually use $L$ instead of $F$! I'd just like to point out though that while I may not have written it out explicitly, what I've written immediately implies the multiplicity of the relative ramifications, I just wrote the bare minimum for someone to understand why this is an answer to the question. I wrote this answer because when I was trying to understand the same question, I didn't understand the terminology in the other answer and it didn't explain why the result was true. At the time I didn't understand how to lift ideals into higher extensions...

Comment: [continued] I wrote this answer so that anyone who finds this question in the future will have a full explanation of how to solve the question, without having any prior knowledge of lifting ideals, since anyone who already knows the result given in the other answer would immediately see how to answer the question.